# How to create a loop to display all the data from XML field?

Tags: php, xml

I would like to create the code to extract all the data from an XML field. I have some knowledge of PHP but I am far from good knowledge.

I have an XML file and I would like to show all the Infos that come from certain fields.

I managed to extract on all the fields which will have only one value per field.

But there is the field "WorkingTimes" which can have 2 values at once. I need to show both of them (when they exist)

I attached a screenshot to help you understand better what I need. Right now, for the other field I use the following code (just an example):

```
<?php
if(isset($xml->jobPublication)) {
    foreach($xml->jobPublication as $job) {
        echo "<h3>".$job->jobOpening->location."</h3>";
        }
    }
?>
```

This will print the value from the Field Location. It is always 1 value.

So, I would need help for the field "WorkingTimes" which can show 2 values.

Thank you in advance, any help would be appreciated.

[image: Here is my screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

Give it a try

```
<?php
if(isset($xml->jobPublication)) {
    foreach($xml->jobPublication as $job) {
        echo "<h3>".$job->jobOpening->location."</h3>";
        foreach($job->jobOpening->workingTimes->workTime as $wrkTime){
        echo "<p>".$wrkTime->name."</p>";
        }
        }
    }
?>
```

Comment: Hello, thanks for your respone. I tried your solution. It also shows only 1 value. This field (WorkingTimes) can have also 2 values at the same time. For example, 1 job can be full-time(value1) or half-time(value2) or both (fulltime and halftime). When it has both, it needs to show both values.

Comment: okay, can you give me your complete xml having 2 values of working times? any link so that I can view it

Comment: the xml can be found here: https://geers-karriere.dvinci.de/portal/intranet/jobPublication/list.xml?lang=de. You should look at the entry: Fachberater Hörakustik (m/w) - ID 129. Thank you

Comment: Can you confirm xml link, there is no data shown in this link.